# mod re-write OS X 10.6

Tags: apache, macos, mod-rewrite

I have OS X 10.6 and am working on a website. When I look at the http.conf file in /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

it appears that the mod-rewrite module is loaded yet when I add a simple .htaccess file to the root of my site, it doesn't seem to do anything:

Options +FollowSymLinks RewriteEngine on RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|index.html|static|admin_static|admin2_static|images|css|js|robots.txt) RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

How can I ensure mod-re-write is working?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you would get better results from this at server fault?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I got it working by editing my user specific conf file.